# Scala on Google App Engine with Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scala, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create web app on pure Scala code. I use last version of Google plugin for Eclipse to create App Engine Web project. After it I add Scala nature to project. I rewrite standart Java servlet generated by Google plugin to Scala servlet version. Everything fine, no scala code errors found. But Eclipse show me some errors in my Scala servlet code like this:

> Unexpected error while validating
>   ScalaServlet.scala.

This error generated by `com.google.appengine.eclipse.core` plugin. I can't understand, where I can fix this error ?

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the project Properties -> Builders, move Scala Builder to top of the list

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of threading support, GAE isn't the best place for Scala code.

I'd recommend you check out Stax: http://www.stax.net/

Amongst other features, they let you build/deploy with Maven, so you're not forced into the non-standard directory layout that Google's eclipse plugins so frequently insist upon.

They also use scala internally, and seem very willing to help out with scala-related issues.

Comment: stax does not actually appear to be live yet - their pricing page mentions that paid upgrades are "coming soon".  in the meantime all that is available is the free but limited slices.